# PHP encode/encrypt array to certain character length

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, payment-gateway

I am making a payment process via PHP possible, for which I need to pass a unique ID which is an alphanumeric character string of **maximum length of 19 characters**.

```
<?php
$amount = $amt; // amount of payment (ex- 20 for 20$)
$uniqNum = $uniqueID; //a string of maximum 19 charatcers
//Now rest of payment happens
?>
```

And while the payment gets processed, user get returned to my website with some GET parameters, of which, the parameter "uniqID" is the same as sent(as mentioned above).

```
<?php
//This will receive
$pfs_voucher_id = $_GET["p96"];     //Transaction ID (identifies invoices etc)
$order_number = $_GET["p120"];      //Sent by me as Unique ID
//rest of logic to get IPN
if($ipn_response == 'Y')
{
 echo "Payment of UniqueID ".$order_number." has been succeeded";
//I got the order number but still couldn't tell to whom this order was meant to
}
?>
```

Since I receive not much information about the payment other than the amount and status of payment, it compelled me to use the unique ID to identify other information regarding the payment such as which user made the payment and what package had he chosen.

One way of doing this(recognizing user) is to store necessary information in the database when user decides to make the payment, generating my own unique id of certain characters, for example-

```
<?php
//Function to generate a unique "Human-readable" string of certain length
function randomly($length=6)
    {
    $conso=array("b","c","d","f","g","h","j","k","l","m","n","p","r","s","t","v","w","x","y","z");
        $vocal=array("a","e","i","o","u");
        $unique="";
        do{
        srand ((double)microtime()*1000000);
        $max = $length/2;
        for($i=1; $i<=$max; $i++)
        {
        $unique.=$conso[rand(0,19)];
        $unique.=$vocal[rand(0,4)];
        }
        }while(exists_in_database($unique) == true);
        return $unique;
    }
//Check if the string is found in the database
function exists_in_database($str)
{
//Since I am using `payments` table to save unique IDs, I must check if it already exists
//@ Using codeigniter
$this->db->select('*')->from('payments')->where('uniqid',$str);
$query = $this->db->get();
if($query->num_rows() > 0)  return true;
else return false;
}
 //generate a unique id of 6 characters
  $uniqid = randomly();
  //Get other info about payments
  $userid = get_loggedin_user(); //get the userid of loggedin user
  $packageid = $this->input->post('packageid'); //or $_POST['packageid']
  $packagename = $this->package->getpackage($packageid)->name; //fetch package name from database
  //Now save the record in payments table with payment status as pending
  $data = array("uniqid"=>$uniqid,"userid"-> $userid, "pkg_id"=>$packageid,"pkg_name"=>$packagename,"pay_status"=>'pending');
 $this->db->insert('payments',$data);
?>
```

and when user returns to the site after payment, check if the uniqueid received exists on database or not. if so, make the status as received.

```
    <?php
    //This will receive
    $pfs_voucher_id = $_GET["p96"];     //Transaction ID (identifies invoices etc)
    $order_number = $_GET["p120"];      //Sent by me as Unique ID
    //rest of logic to get IPN
    if($ipn_response == 'Y')
    {
     $query = $this->db->where('uniqid',$order_number)->get('payments');
     $payment = isset($query->userid)?$query:null;
     if(isset($query->userid))
{
     echo "Payment of UniqueID ".$order_number." has been succeeded";
    //I got the order number and now I can tell the user it corresponds to
 $data = array("uniqid"=>$order_number,"userid"-> $query->userid,"pay_status"=>'Completed');
     $this->db->update('payments',$data); //update the payment status to complete
}
    }
    ?>
```

But the problem of going this way would be the unlimited number of entries which would still exist if user does not pay or cancels the payment. The cancel URL would not receive the unique ID and where I am unable to delete the pending status of payment regarding him. So, a better idea would be to insert the payment only when "OK" response is received from payment gateway.

So, I want to know how to encrypt/encode the required details (userid and package id atleast) into a unique ID of 19 characters or less, so I can validate information. I would also glad to know if you can suggest any better way of doing so.

```
<?php
function encode_arr($data) {
    return base64_encode(serialize($data));
}

function decode_arr($data) {
    return unserialize(base64_decode($data));
}

$uniqid = encode_arr(array('userid'=>$userid,'pkgid'=>$packageid,'timestamp'=>now()));
?>
```

I tried making an array of userid and package and serializing it and base64 encoding it to make a unique string out of it.But to make it more unique, I am thinking about adding timestamp too that would be helpful about the transaction time. But that will certainly exceed my 19 characters limit. Should I go for hashing/encryption technique?

PS: I am using codeigniter if that do any help.

Comment: What's wrong with having "abandoned" pending payments in your database? If you know they're incomplete (and you do, since you haven't changed them from "pending" to "completed"), you can ignore them and delete them if they're older than some threshold. If you use your first approach (and learn to live with the incomplete orders), you can use the table ID as your unique ID and store as much data about the order as you like in the database.

Comment: just delete records older than a month or so with a monthly cronjob

Comment: @Kryten i appreciate what you suggest. I also have thought the similar. But Just that someone accidently clicks the payment link would cause an entry in the database and hence someone can just randomize this process, causing a DDOS or something. This opens up a new scenario to handle the database. Which is safer then the other process. Isn't that so?

Comment: It doesn't seem to me that writing a record to your database is necessarily going to make your site more likely to fail when subject to a DDOS attack; if your web server can't keep up with the traffic during a DDOS attack, it's going to fail. If you're worried about cleaning up in the aftermath of a DDOS attack, that shouldn't be too difficult: `DELETE FROM orders WHERE status='pending' AND order_time BETWEEN <start of DDOS attack> AND <end of DDOS attack>';`